# Windows 10 UWP App XElement.Save() "Access is denied" exception

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a Windows 10 UWP App, and I'm hitting a snag. I have a Settings.xml in the root of the app folder that I will use to store the DB connection information, as well as a few ancillary settings. I can load the XML fine, and my function to edit works (I can extract the XML through debug and see the changes). My problem comes when trying to write the edited file. I understand that I don't have direct access to the file system with UWP, however I've tried several different methods I've found online to work within my constraints and still can't find one that works. I always come back with an "Access is denied" error in some form or another. Here is a snippet of what my Save function looks like right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
try
{
    XElement xmlSettings = XElement.Load(uri: "Settings.xml");
    XElement xmlNode;

    //Do Stuff (clipped for brevity).

    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName: "Settings.xml", options: CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    xmlSettings.Save(stream);

    Error = "";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Error = "SaveSettings";
}
```

Comment: Does *Settings.xml* come with your package? Where is the file located? You download/create it in *LocalFolder*?

Comment: Hi Romasz,

I created the file myself. It is in the root of my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an xml file to my solution (in the root) and copy pasted your code.
It runs the first time, but gets the exception the second time. The reason is that your stream is not closed. You should use it with using:

```
using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    xmlSettings.Save(stream);
}
```

With this change the code worked even the second time.

Comment: Hi Akos,

Thank you so much for pointing that out. It fixed my problem entirely!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!